# Restart java virtual machine in case of failure

Tags: java, jvm, fault-tolerance

There are some really horrible scenarios that could happen to java virtual machine. Something more dreadful than uncaught exception, like an error. So I'd like to restart application automatically in this case in recover mode and clean resources that it have dropped half-way.

What is robust method to restart java machine on failure? Google suggests some general purpose baby-sitters like daemon tools, but I search for more platform independent and java-oriented solution. Like a native extension for example.

Comment: "Platform independent" and "native extension" in the same paragraph?

Comment: It may be written in platform-independent way. Many common baby sitters is already tied to unix systems

Comment: you could use a small java program to launch and supervise the other one, use jnr if you need posix apis

Answer (score 0):

What I do is have a shell script which checks the exit code.  If the exit code is an error it restarts the problem in a loop. Otherwise the shell script exits.